# ORA-02292 Constraint violation - child records found

Tags: hibernate, jpa, seam

parent entity is consits of many to may relation when ever i deleted the parent Id I give the excetion is ORA-02292 Constraint violation - child records found.

My Entity :

@Entity

@Table(name = "MOBEE_AGENCY")

public class MobeeAgency implements java.io.Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long id;

private Set<MobeeAgent> mobeeAgents = new HashSet<MobeeAgent>(0);
private Set<MobeeAgcyAccounts> mobeeAgcyAccountses = new HashSet<MobeeAgcyAccounts>(
        0);

private Set<MobeeAgencyRegion> MobeeAgencyRegions = new HashSet<MobeeAgencyRegion>(0);




@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "MOBEE_AGENCY_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "MOBEE_AGENCY_SEQ", sequenceName = "MOBEE_AGENCY_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "ID")
public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}



@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "APP_ID")
public MobeeRegProcess getMobeeRegProcess() {
    return this.mobeeRegProcess;
}

public void setMobeeRegProcess(MobeeRegProcess mobeeRegProcess) {
    this.mobeeRegProcess = mobeeRegProcess;
}





@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mobeeAgency")
public Set<MobeeAgent> getMobeeAgents() {
    return this.mobeeAgents;
}

public void setMobeeAgents(Set<MobeeAgent> mobeeAgents) {
    this.mobeeAgents = mobeeAgents;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mobeeAgency")
public Set<MobeeAgcyAccounts> getMobeeAgcyAccountses() {
    return this.mobeeAgcyAccountses;
}

public void setMobeeAgcyAccountses(
        Set<MobeeAgcyAccounts> mobeeAgcyAccountses) {
    this.mobeeAgcyAccountses = mobeeAgcyAccountses;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "mobeeAgency")
public Set<MobeeAgencyRegion> getMobeeAgencyRegions() {
    return MobeeAgencyRegions;
}

public void setMobeeAgencyRegions(Set<MobeeAgencyRegion> mobeeAgencyRegions) {
    MobeeAgencyRegions = mobeeAgencyRegions;
}
```

}

Getting Exception Is:

> 13:29:56,226 INFO  [STDOUT] [Mobee]- INFO 2012-07-01 13:29:56,225 []
>   MobeeAgencyHome - deleting Records for the Agency 832859 13:29:56,251
>   INFO  [STDOUT] [Mobee]- WARN 2012-07-01 13:29:56,251 []
>   JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 2292, SQLState: 23000 13:29:56,251
>   INFO  [STDOUT] [Mobee]-ERROR 2012-07-01 13:29:56,251 []
>   JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-02292: integrity constraint
>   (KCBUSER.FK6B6B82ABC89B1A0C) violated - child record found
>   13:29:56,251 INFO  [STDOUT] [Mobee]- WARN 2012-07-01 13:29:56,251 []
>   JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 2292, SQLState: 23000 13:29:56,251
>   INFO  [STDOUT] [Mobee]-ERROR 2012-07-01 13:29:56,251 []
>   JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-02292: integrity constraint
>   (KCBUSER.FK6B6B82ABC89B1A0C) violated - child record found
>   13:29:56,253 INFO  [STDOUT] [Mobee]-ERROR 2012-07-01 13:29:56,251 []
>   AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state
>   with session org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:
>   Could not execute JDBC batch update   at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:92)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:87)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:222)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2479)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2697)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:74)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:234)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:146)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)  at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:296)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.persistence.EntityManagerProxy.flush(EntityManagerProxy.java:92)
>     at org.jboss.seam.framework.EntityHome.update(EntityHome.java:64)   at
>   com.manam.mobee.agency.MobeeAgencyHome.update(MobeeAgencyHome.java:2599)
>     at
>   com.manam.mobee.agency.MobeeAgencyHome.processUserDecision(MobeeAgencyHome.java:2465)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)   at
>   org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.core.BijectionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(BijectionInterceptor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.core.ConversationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(ConversationInterceptor.java:56)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor$1.work(TransactionInterceptor.java:97)
>     at org.jboss.seam.util.Work.workInTransaction(Work.java:47)     at
>   org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.aroundInvoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.security.SecurityInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:163)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
>     at
>   com.manam.mobee.agency.MobeeAgencyHome_$$_javassist_seam_15.processUserDecision(MobeeAgencyHome_$$_javassist_seam_15.java)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:335)
>     at
>   org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:280)
>     at
>   org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.getValue(AstMethodSuffix.java:59)
>     at
>   org.jboss.el.parser.AstMethodSuffix.invoke(AstMethodSuffix.java:65)
>     at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)    at
>   org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
>     at
>   com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:77)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:91)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:383)    at
>   org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.broadcast(AjaxActionComponent.java:55)
>     at
>   org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:324)
>     at
>   org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:299)
>     at
>   org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:256)
>     at
>   org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:469)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:97)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:244)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:530)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:445)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:292)
>     at org.jboss.seam.web.RewriteFilter.process(RewriteFilter.java:98)
>     at org.jboss.seam.web.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:57)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>     at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>     at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>     at
>   org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
>     at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
>     at
>   org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
>     at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)     at
>   org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)    at
>   org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>     at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
>     at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:
>   13:29:56,253 INFO  [STDOUT] 158)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-02292: integrity constraint
>   (KCBUSER.FK6B6B82ABC89B1A0C) violated - child record found

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove your children when removing the entity

@Cascade(DELETE_ORPHAN)

if JPA 2 you can do

@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)

Answer (score 1):

Just check:

```
select distinct lvl cleanup_order, t1 clean_table, t2 to_clean_table 
from 
(SELECT level lvl, t2, t1, i2, c1, c2
FROM
  (
    SELECT c1.owner, c1.table_name t1, c2.table_name t2, c2.index_name i2,
      c1.constraint_name c1, c2.constraint_name c2
    FROM user_constraints c1, user_constraints c2
    WHERE c1.constraint_type = 'R'
    AND c1.r_constraint_name = c2.constraint_name
    AND c1.r_owner           = c2.owner
  )
  ov
  START WITH t2       in ('YOUR_TABLE_YOU_WANT_DELETE')  ---List tables which have to be cleaned.
  CONNECT BY prior T1 = T2) lvl
 -- where t1 is not NULL
  order by lvl desc, to_clean_table;
```